# How to find the locus of the complex equation : $z \overline{z} +az +b\overline{z}+c=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find the locus of the complex equation :

$z \overline{z} +az +b\overline{z}+c=0$

I have no clue how to find the locus of such equation in complex plane. Please guide on this thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$, then $z\overline z = x^2+y^2$ so, assuming $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, our equation splits into the real part
$$
x^2+y^2 + (a+b)x + c = 0
$$
and the imaginary part
$$
(a- b)y = 0.
$$
If $a\neq b$ this implies $y=0$ and you are left with a quadratic equation in $x$.

If $a=b$ the second equation is always true and the first equation becomes
$$
x^2+y^2 + 2ax + c =0.
$$
Completing the square for $x$ gives you
$$
(x+a)^2+y^2 = a^2 - c
$$
which is the equation of a circle centered at $-a$.

Comment: (Assuming that a, b, c are *real* numbers.)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I forgot to mention I assumed that.